# The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

So I have this math problem and I don't know how to solve it...

**Find $f(4)$** $$\int_0^{x^2} f(t) \, dt= x\cos(\pi x)$$

This is what I came up with but I have no idea if it is right or what to do next. $$F(x^2)-F(0)=x(\cos\pi x)$$

Comment: You need to assume continuity of $f$ at $4$ and differentiate the given equation using FTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iulius Caesar said: DERIVE AND RULE.

$$\cos(\pi x)-\pi x\sin(\pi x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\cos(\pi x)\right) =\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{x^2}f(t)dt=2x f(x^2).$$

Hence, $\cos(\pi x)-\pi x\sin(\pi x)=2x f(x^2)$, and you are done:

$$f(4)=1/4.$$

EDIT:

Start with $2xf(x^2)=\cos(\pi x)-\pi x \sin(\pi x)$ and take $x=2$. So $$4f(4)=\cos (2\pi)-2\pi\sin(2\pi)=1,$$ so $f(4)=1/4$.

Comment: Well, $f(2^2)=1/4$.

Comment: OUCH!!!! Thanks @vrugtehagel

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Differentiation with respect to $x$ yields
\begin{align}
&\frac{d}{dx}(F(x^2)-F(0)) = F'(x^2)\cdot 2x - 0 = 2xf(x^2)\\
&\frac{d}{dx}(x\cos(\pi x)) = \cos(\pi x)-\pi x\sin(\pi x).
\end{align}

Comment: Hint 2: We now know that $$ 2xf(x^2)=\cos(\pi x) - \pi x \sin(\pi x). $$ For which value(s) of $x$ will this equality tell you something about $f(4)$?

Comment: How did we know that $F(0) = 0$?

Comment: @NoChance We don't know that. What we know is that $F(0)$ is a constant and that therefore $\frac{d}{dx}F(0) = 0.$

Comment: @DavidK, of course, thanks for clarifying this.

Answer (score 1):

By inplicit differentiation, we have

$$ f(x^2) 2x = \cos ( \pi x ) - \pi x \sin ( \pi x ) $$

Therefore, since $x= \pm 2$ when $x^2=4$, evaluate at each point to get your solution

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be the answer required by your teacher, I find it interesting and it **may be valid**:

Usint FTC, with lower bound zero:

$$\int_0^{b} f(t) \, dt= F(b)-F(0)$$

We are given:
$$\int_0^{x^2} f(t) \, dt= x\cos(\pi x)$$

So we have:

$$F(x^2)-F(0) = x\cos(\pi x)$$

By inspection, in other words, how did we get the R.H.S of the above equation? Think of the R.H.S in terms of $t$, what function of $t$ we can use such that:

$$F(t=x^2)= x\cos(\pi x)$$

Knowing that $\sqrt {t^2}=t (or -t)$, we could say that:

$$F(t)=\sqrt{t}\cos \left(\pi\:\sqrt{t}\right)$$

to get $f(t)$, we need to take the derivative of both sides:

$$ \frac{d}{dt}F(t)=f(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\cos \left(\pi \sqrt{t}\right)\sqrt{t}\right)=-\frac{\pi \sin \left(\pi \sqrt{t}\right)}{2}+\frac{\cos \left(\pi \sqrt{t}\right)}{2\sqrt{t}}$$

$$f(4)=0+\frac{cos(2\pi)}{2*2}=\frac{1}{4}$$ or

$$f(4)=0+\frac{cos(-2\pi)}{2*(-2)}=\frac{1}{-4}$$